# How to get ReactJS to render empty HTML attributes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to get React to render an empty attribute, but instead it's not including it at all.  Any ideas?

```
render(){
    return <myComponent foo="{ this.state.foo }" />
}
```

when `this.state.foo` if falsey, this yields:

```
<mycomponent />
```

whereas I want:

```
<myComponent foo />
```

Comment: @Alexander -- Thanks, but `componentDidMount` only runs once, and the general concept of manually setting attributes via DOM access is very anti-react :)

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is not that the attribute value is blank; it's that your attribute is neither a native html spec element or prefaced with `data`.  From the [JSX Gotchas](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-gotchas.html#custom-html-attributes) pages:

> If you pass properties to native HTML elements that do not exist in the HTML specification, React will not render them. If you want to use a custom attribute, you should prefix it with data-.

You should do something like this:

```
render(){
    return <myComponent data-foo={ this.state.foo || '' } />
}
```

**Update (as @alexander pointed out):**

You also need to specify a backup empty string if data-foo can return null.  I've updated my example

Comment: Sorry, it already is a `data-` attr (wasn't paying attention to that when writing the example code), still not showing up.  http://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/2489/